# Указатели для создания виджетов

Tags: c++, qt

Почему при создании виджета нужно использовать указатель, а не переменную?

Так не работает:

```
QPushButton examplePushButton = new QPushButton();
```

А так работает:

```
QPushButton *examplePushButton = new QPushButton();
```

Comment: Посмотрите на сообщение компилятора. Справа и слева от `=` - разные типы.

Comment: @Igor Ошибка: conversion from 'QPushButton*' to non-scalar type 'QPushButton' requested
             QPushButton examplePushButton = new QPushButton();

Comment: Вопрос не имеет никакого отношения к виджетам и Qt. Вопрос об основах языка С++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для создания переменной с типом виджета, и его инициализации, есть 2 способа:

1.

```
QPushButton push_button(/* some params goes here */);
// аналогично вызову new QPushButton(...);
```

2.

```
QPushButton push_button;
// это уже объект, не нужно ничего вызывать. аналогия new QPushButton();
```

Однако, вы должны помнить, и знать о том, что локальные переменные имеют ограниченное время жизни, и ограничены они обычно областью видимости функций, или методов.

В то время, когда выделенная память из кучи для того же объекта при помощи оператора `new`, ограничение времени жизни отсутствует, или же протекает дор тех пор, пока вы явно не удалите этот объект вызовом оператора `delete`, или приложение не будет завершено.